# Tooltip in fullcalendar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

everyone!
I'm trying to show tooltip over events in fullcalendar. But it's not working and show in console this message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

What can be a problem? This is my js-function code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(function() {
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: event.title,
            container: "body"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing function. You should pass your options and callbacks. Read [Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   //Removed function() from here
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: event.title,
            container: "body"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct, you have to pass a configuration _object_, not a function.

Answer (score 7):

In FullCalendar 4, use eventRender function:

```
eventRender: function (info) {
  $(info.el).tooltip({ title: info.event.title });     
}
```

Comment: you've missed the point of the question. The accepted answer dealt with it years ago. And an answer for v4 is irrelevant for **this** issue, anyway.

Comment: I get tooltip not defined